# What is the name of this topological space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let $X=\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$ and let the open sets be the set of unions of sets of the form $U_n=\{k\in X : k|n\}$.

Is there a name for this space? Google is not helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the *Divisor Topology* in Steen/Seebach's **Counterexamples in Topology**, Example 57 on pp. 79-80 of the 1978 2nd edition (same location in the 1995 Dover reprint of the 2nd edition). Googling, I see there is a Wikipedia article for the [Divisor Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_topology).